# How to POST login to an Action Message Format (flash based) page?

Tags: flash, google-chrome-devtools, amf

First time I've come across a page like this. [US Bank example](https://uniteus.usbank.com/)

There is no option to inspect when I right click the page. Anyone know how to work with a page like this? I eventually need access to the form so I can post credentials and do some automation. Any help appreciated. Thanks

The page has `Content-Type: application/x-amf`.

Comment: Just ask them... Explain your app and if its legal they should help you (ie; maybe check if they provide a non-AMF method to receive the same data of that form, maybe using some API or even JSON entries or similar).

Comment: I will look to do that. Thank you for your input!